# Error on nvm initialisation on jenkins shell that runs in a MAC slave

Tags: macos, jenkins, nvm

When I run the command `source $HOME/.zshrc` on Jenkins shell, that runs on a MAC slave, I get the following error in the nvm initialisation:

```
nvm_err 'N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed.
nvm_err 'You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it.'
```

The error does not occurs on local machine, only on jenkins shell. The contents of the `.zshrc` that crashes is this:

```
# NVM
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

However, this is the script of the recommended initialisation of nvm, and it is added automatically on nvm installation. Anyone knows what may cause this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [article](http://yura.stryi.com/en/2018-04-26/NVM-with-Jenkins/) that has an workaround to this problem. This worked for me. In resume, I had just to set the property `+ex` to make the shell ignore the immediate errors temporarily:

```
set +ex
source $HOME/.zshrc
set -ex
```